# Checkstyle CustomImportOrder more than 3 definable groups?

Tags: checkstyle

My company's Java import order standard would require more than the three definable groups that I see in checkstle, which are `STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE`, `THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE`, and `SPECIAL_IMPORTS`.  My question has two parts:

1. Is there a way to define more custom regular expressions, or use regexes directly in the VALUE for customImportOrderRules?
2. Can I do this at all, since com.our_company is supposed to come after all the other com. imports.

The import rules are approximately

1. Static imports
2. java.*
3. javax.*
4. com.* EXCEPT our company
5. nthing.*
6. org.*
7. pthing.*
8. com.mycompany.*
9. anything else

Since we also enforce blank lines between groups, I can't combine 5, 6, and 7 into one and depend on sort order to keep things clean.  Worst case is that we already have this defined in Intellij and just have to remember to auto-order imports every time.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions:

1. According to [this ticket](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/8241) it looks like there is no way to achieve what you need using just [CustomImportOrder](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#CustomImportOrder). Instead you should use [ImportOrder](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#ImportOrder), complete example below.
2. It is possible using [ImportOrder](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#ImportOrder)

This should work for your case:

```
<module name="ImportOrder">
    <property name="option" value="top"/>
    <property name="groups" value="/^java\./,javax,/^com\.(?!mycompany)/,nthing.org,pthing,com.mycompany"/>
    <property name="ordered" value="true"/>
    <property name="separated" value="true"/>
    <property name="separatedStaticGroups" value="true"/>
    <property name="sortStaticImportsAlphabetically" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Small clarification. Inside the `groups` property there are two groups `/^com\.(?!mycompany)/` and `com.mycompany`, first one is the regexp that use [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), second one is just common prefix string for the import.